# Spring reflection: Get original method from proxied method

Tags: spring

Consider having `Method` myMethod which is on proxied class `MyClass`. It's name is altered similar to `CGLIB$myMethod$` and the annotations of the original method are not available.

I need to find the method `myMethod` with annotation `@MyAnnotation`:

```
Method method = ...
method.getName().contains("$myMethod$")) && method.findAnnotation<MyAnnotation>() != null
```

The first part of the condition is working even though a bit hacky, but the annotation will not be found. Is there a way to access the original method from the proxied one?

Comment: You can create an object from proxy. And then get the annotation. May be not a great idea. but its an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you think of creating a wrapper/decorator over `MyClass` that in turn will become a Proxy and `MyClass` instance will be of a regular (non-proxied) class?

UPD: also you may try `AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(...)` or `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(...)` methods

Comment: This helped for the annotation, but I still cannot get to the proxied method.